# Проблема с версиями Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pymorphy2

Всем привет, проблема с версиями на Питоне из-за неумелых манипуляций, в результате не могу установить библиотеки с помощью cmd и IDE Pycharm, а так же сам запуск через Pycharm.

Я пыталась отчистить с компа все файлы Python (в том числе из path путей), но не могу удалить файлы python.exe и python3.exe по адресу C:Users/darku/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps.

При удалении всего кроме этих двух файлов, cmd при команде python переправляет на Misrosoft Store с просьбой приобрести Python 3.7.5

Скачала и установила Python 3.7.5 в итоге cmd при команде python позволяет писать коды. Версия pip новейшая. Некоторые библиотеки, например, nump, устанавливать позволяет, а некоторые, например, pymorphy2, нет.

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\darku\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\darku\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\\pymorphy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\darku\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\\pymorphy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pymorphy\morph.py", line 2, in <module>
        from pymorphy_speedups._morph import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymorphy_speedups'

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        from pymorphy.version import __version__
      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pymorphy\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pymorphy.morph import get_morph
      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pymorphy\morph.py", line 10, in <module>
        from pymorphy._morph import *
      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pymorphy\_morph.py", line 6, in <module>
        from pymorphy.constants import *
      File "C:\Users\darku\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-s6sp3zyv\pymorphy\pymorphy\constants.py", line 83, in <module>
        RU_TENSES_STANDARD.items() + RU_VOICES_STANDARD.items())
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image: описание ошибки]

Comment: Ну, проблема решилась.
Все дело было в антивируснике, который запрещал скачивать некоторые библиотеки

Comment: Оформи лучше как ответ. Ну и название антивиря тоже не помешает.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

Итак, проблема решена: удалила антивирус, который больше всего влиял на производительность (в моем случае COMODO)

Comment: `Kaspersky free` очень неплох. Присмотрись при случае.